# Cast from uint8_t* to StringRef

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-3.0

I'm using ExecutionEngine.cpp. I want to get StringRef from found addresses by the following code:

`const APInt &IntVal;`

`uint8_t *y2 = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(const_cast<uint64_t *>(IntVal.getRawData()));`

`int v2 = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(y2);`

`StringRef* Src1V=cast<StringRef>(y2);`

I got this error:

`home/rasha/llvm/llvm/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:236:3:   required from ‘typename llvm::cast_retty<X, Y*>::ret_type llvm::cast(Y*) [with X = llvm::StringRef; Y = unsigned char; typename llvm::cast_retty<X, Y*>::ret_type = llvm::StringRef*]’`

`/home/rasha/llvm/llvm/lib/ExecutionEngine/Interpreter/Execution.cpp:1291:38:   required from here`

`/home/rasha/llvm/llvm/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:56:28: error: ‘classof’ is not a member of ‘llvm::StringRef’`

`return To::classof(&Val);`

Would you please explain to me the error?
Note that I used the casting with the same types in Execution.cpp, with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are all represented inside the LLVM IR as `ConstantDataSequential`, subclass of Constant. if you want stringref, you must explicitly tell LLVM to do that for you by calling corresponding APIs of `ConstantDataSequential`.
To be specific, you need to call one or more of the following LLVM API after casting the pointer you get:

- `isString (unsigned CharSize=8)`
- `isCString ()`
- `getAsString ()`
- `getAsCString ()`